# Django Project Documentation Type of Relationship

Tags: django, django-models, documentation

I am documenting a Django Project that deals with objects **Store**,  **Person**,  **Transaction**, and **Address**

*I would appreciate you reading the thing just as sanity check to me but my real question is in the last paragraph.*

*Only Showing The Fields Which Are a Relation*

**Store**

```
# The intention here is for each Store to have exactly 1 address that can not be shared with another Store.
# I represent this on my diagram  as 1-to-1   Store --> Address
address = models.OneToOneField(Address, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

**Person**

```
# The intention here is for each Person (used for Employee and Customers) to have exactly 1 address that can not be shared with another Person.
# I represent this on my diagram as 1-to-1   Person --> Address
address = models.OneToOneField(Address, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

# The intention here is for many Persons to be associated with a Store.
# In this case the association would mean they were an employee of the Store.
# There is a dummpy Store that all customers are associated with (I know not the best design)
# I am represting this relationship as Many-to-1  Person --> Store
store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

**Address**

```
# No relation fields
```

**Transaction**

```
# The intention here is for each Transaction exactly 1 Store that can not be shared with another Store.
# I represent this on my diagram as Many-to-1   Transaction --> Store
store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

# Here is where it gets confusing to me.  A Person(Customer) can have 
# Many transactions with a Store but each Transaction only has 1 Person.
#So would this be a Many-to-1  or a Many-to-Many relation  Transaction --> Person? 
# The way it is defined currently works correctly. I am mostly asking about this conceptually.
person = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is valid for Transaction -> Person relation. Just think another way to understand. When you filter Transaction model with person_id, you will get the records (which may be multiple) belongs to that person. So there is nothing to change in definition. In the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/), you can find message "To define a many-to-one relationship, use ForeignKey" in Many-To-One Relationships section.